# Can inner class inherit from outer class?

Tags: python, inheritance, inner-classes

My plan is to represent an Mobile website:
Website has three tabs, A,B,C
I want to have A,B,C as inner classes, as switching between tabs changes layout and should re-initialize objects (previous one will become stale).
However, There are parts of layout common for all tabs, therefore i wanted to have such methods in one place, instead have three redundant copies for each tab.
My idea was to have an abstract outer class (cannot really make it abstract - legacy mistake in project structure, that i cannot change), that has common methods for all tabs, and three classes for each tab. Smth like:

```
class Website(...):
   def common_method(self):
       pass
   class A(Website):
      def a_tab_method_only(self):
          pass
   class B(Website):
      def b_tab_method_only(self):
          pass
   class C(Website):
      def c_tab_method_only(self):
          pass
```

I want to disallow calling the `Website` class, but use code like:

```
Website.C.c_tab_method_only()
```

As this looks like nice code line and seems logical but i cannot make this:

```
class A(Website):
```

...because PyCharm doesn't see it, and form:

```
class A (package.Website)
```

makes circular import, obviously

**Help me StackOverflow masters!**

Comment: no, that is not how it works. you're not adding any functionality by nesting these classes. 
You probably want a ABC. However, why would you 'disallow' in the first place?

Comment: @Alex, you are right, I cannot. What I disallowed is, disallowed to me. My project, by legacy, depends on more generic one - poorly designed one (or maybe never designed to do, what it currently does). The inheritance goes further to those classes, and those, even if should be abstract, are just partially, and do not inherit ABC. Therefore children of those classes cannot as well (an abstract class cannot inherit form non-abstract, only other way - and it it reasonable). For now, I use another, private class that does inheritance, while nesting acts as - code purifier and hierarchy keeper